# Are there any aircraft with a 4-wheel nose landing gear and a 16-wheel main landing gear?

Tags: aircraft-design, landing-gear

Are there any aircraft with a 4-wheel nose landing gear and a 16-wheel main landing gear? I need this to answer my review of an aircraft design project.

Comment: I'm curious. How will finding such an aircraft help with a review of some other design?

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan "If they did it so can we!" :)

Answer (score 30):

The Il-76:

[image]

4 main bogies with 4 wheels each, nose gear with 4 wheels.

this one has a better view of the wheels, but it's a CGI:

[image]

4-wheel nose gear is rare, 16-wheel mains are more common: Boeing 747 (4 trucks with 4 wheels each in 2x2 config), Avro Vulcan (main trucks with 2 axles with 4 wheels each), HP Victor (same as Vulcan), Shorts Belfast (same as Vulcan).

Answer (score 26):

[The Antonov AN-124 has 4 nose wheels and 20 mains which is close to that configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-124_Ruslan).

[The Antonov AN-225 is also close to being configured this way.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-225_Mriya) It has 4 nose wheels but has 32 mains.

[image]

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-225_Mriya#/media/File:Antonov_An-225_landing_at_Gostomel_Airport.jpeg))

Comment: That is one ***MASSIVE*** #@$§¥& airplane! Just, ***dang***!

Comment: Not to mention a beautiful one!

Comment: C-5 has 4 front and 24 mains, but can be misconstrued as 16 from some angles.

Comment: I can only count 28 main wheels for AN-225 on that picture.

Comment: Can't find a good picture of the landing gear, but the Stratolaunch looks like it has either 24 or 48 main wheels, and 4 or 8 nose wheels.

Comment: @jamesqf there's plenty of "Stratolaunch" pictures with simple Google search. It has 24 main (6*4) and 4 front wheels.

Comment: @Alex: There are lots of Stratolaunch pictures, but none of the several dozen I looked at (the first couple of pages when searching for "stratolaunch landing gear") showed the landing gear clearly enough for me to tell whether there were single or double wheels on the gear.  (I mean that for instance each nose gear could have had 4 wheels, like the C-5.

Comment: @jamesqf I think this one is the clearest picture I could find: https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/zAkCXEBBjgwzNTE37zLnZC.jpeg

Answer (score 14):

I'd like to mention the Lockheed [C-5 Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_C-5_Galaxy), which has 4 nose wheels and 24 mains.
[image: C-5][[source]](https://news.lockheedmartin.com/2018-08-06-Lockheed-Martin-Delivers-52nd-C-5M-Super-Galaxy#assets_all)

The large Antonovs use two two-wheel bogies for their nose gear, whereas the C-5 uses one four-wheel bogey. For the mains, the Antonovs have multiple inline two-wheel bogies, whereas the C-5 has four six-wheel bogies. As Moo [commented](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/77502/are-there-any-aircraft-with-a-4-wheel-nose-landing-gear-and-a-16-wheel-main-land/77516#comment203017_77503) while I was writing this, those distinctive six-wheel bogies can be deceptive from some angles and give the appearance of 16 main wheels.

Comment: A tricycle undercarriage, where the main gear comprises four tricycle undercarriages...

Comment: Lockheed know how to triforce.